# A question on continued fraction

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $a$ be a positive irrational number. Let $p_k/q_k, p_{k+1}/q_{k+1}$ be two consecutive
convergents of its simple continued fraction, where $k\ge 1$.

Is it possible that both $$|a-(p_k/q_k)|<1/(2q_k^2)$$ and $$|a-(p_{k+1}/q_{k+1})|<1/(2q_{k+1}^2)$$
are true?

I can only prove that at least one of these inequalities is true.

Comment: Do you have $\lfloor a \rfloor  = p_0/q_0$?

Comment: Yes. That is right.

Answer (score 5):

At least it can happen that not both are true. Example: 333/106 is a convergent to $\pi$, but $(\pi-(333/106)) \cdot 2 \cdot 106^2 \approx 1.87 > 1$.

Comment: But it can also happen for some $a$ and $k$ that both are true. `N[Map[2 (# - Pi) Denominator[#]^2 &, Convergents[Pi,30]],10]` in Mathematica gives a list of numbers which vary somewhat randomly between being $<1$ or $>1$ in absolute value.

Comment: ...and there are places where several consecutive values are $<1$ (but no two consecutive values are $>1$, which agrees with what you claim to have proved).

Comment: Of any two consecutive, at least one of them satisfies the condition in the question. That is true. It is an exercise in the Number Theory book by Niven.

Answer (score 1):

It is known that $$|a-(p_k/q_k)|\le1/(q_kq_{k+1})\le1/(a_{k+1}q_k^2)$$ (see, e.g., Hardy and Wright) so if all the partial quotients exceed 2 then all the convergents satisfy your inequalitites.